# Unable to add a button in fragment using Navigation storyboard to jump from one fragment to another fragment

Tags: java, android, navigation, storyboard

I am trying to add a button in a fragment page to jump from one fragment to another fragment using the method of the navigation storyboard of android studio.
However, in the Mainfragment.java, my button id cannot be resolved, it cannot recognize my button id and I don't know why. Please help!

```
  public MainFragment() {

        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Button goToBtn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.goToBtn);
        goToBtn.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.toAccount, null));


    }
    }
```

For the above codes in `Mainfragment.java`, the `findViewById` is red.

Comment: please refer my answer @TszYing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change below line

```
Button goToBtn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.goToBtn);
```

With

```
Button goToBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.goToBtn);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! And I found that using getView(). can also work.
Are two of them the same usage?

Comment: no is there no any changes. and please if my answer is right then accept as a answer